# Counting occurances of certain variables within "for loop" and/or "while loop" in lua, and identify their index

Tags: loops, lua

I am trying to figure out how many times a certain variable occurs within a for or while loop and then tie them to the correct index (i). I will use letters to give an example of what i've tried.

Ex: "Letterlist(index)" contains random letters from a-z on every index. I want to see how many times the letter b occurs within the loop.

```
for i = 1, 10 do
  B_LetterCount = 0
  letter = Letterlist(i)
  if letter == b then
    B_LetterID = i
    B_LetterCount = B_LetterCount + 1
  end
end
```

As you can probably tell, that loop will not work because the latest occurrence of the letter B will overwrite the id of any of the other occurances. For instance if:

```
1 = a
2 = b
3 = h
4 = b
5 = y
6 = t
7 = a
8 = b
9 = e
10 = k
```

Then b occurs on index 2, 4 and 8. Is there a way to count them and also set an ID variable for them, as shown in my example loop: B_LetterID = i, B_LetterID2 = i and so on.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have not found the solution but I see one problem in your code: you do B_LetterCount = 0 in your for loop so B_LetterCount will always be reset to 0. Try to put B_LetterCount = 0 outside the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, I need to run the loop about every 2 seconds because the letters rearrange and switch indexes. so if I dont reset it, it will keep adding up to 30+ after a few runs allthough there might only be 1 b in the loop. So I also need to do the counting inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it up to you to change the code to your needs. You should get the idea.

```
local list = {"a", "b", "h", "b", "y", "t", "a", "b", "e", "k"}

local indices = {}
local counts = {}
for i,v in ipairs(list) do
  indices[v] = indices[v] or {}
  table.insert(indices[v], i)
  counts[v] = counts[v] and (counts[v] + 1) or 1
end

for k,v in pairs(counts) do
  print(string.format("%d %q at:", v, k)) 
  print(table.unpack(indices[k]))
end
```